# UDP packets waiting and then arriving together

Tags: java, udp

I have a simple Java program which acts as a server, listening for UDP packets. I then have a client which sends UDP packets over 3g.

Something I've noticed is occasionally the following appears to occur: I send one packet and seconds later it is still not received. I then send another packet and suddenly they both arrive.

I was wondering if it was possible that some sort of system is in place to wait for a certain amount of data instead of sending an undersized packet. In my application, I only send around 2-3 bytes of data per packet - although the UDP header and what not will bulk the message up a bit.

The aim of my application is to get these few bytes of data from A to B as fast as possible. Huge emphasis on speed. Is it all just coincidence? I suppose I could increase the packet size, but it just seems like the transfer time will increase, and 3g isn't exactly perfect.

Comment: Stop guessing. Do packet traces. Get **real** data.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is, typically the receiving end will be ordered to retrieve a certain number of bytes before returning--use Wireshark (or similar) to verify whether or not the data is being sent and received on both ends.

Comment: This looks like a job for something like Wireshark.

Comment: @Redmumba Ordered by whom? UDP is UDP. A datagram should be delivered to the application as soon as it is received.

Comment: Right, but if your receiving app says "read(10)" where 10 is the number of bytes to buffer before processing it in your program, your physical machine/socket/whatever may have received those bytes but not buffered enough to trigger the read operation.  Like @Jon said: use Wireshark.

Comment: @Redmumba I don't know what any of this means. There is no such facility. There is no Sockets API that insists on a minimum number of bytes to read before it returns. Nor do I understand the distinction you are drawing between receiving and buffering.

Comment: Well, you mentioned you are using Java; are you using an `InputStream`?  Perhaps a `BufferedInputRead`?  It sounds like your program is not operating on a byte-by-byte basis, but on a larger scale--i.e., its waiting for 4 bytes before `select()` returns and your program receives data.  Not to sound redundant (its been mentioned 3 times), but have you used Wireshark to verify that the packets are, indeed, not making it to your computer, and not that its an issue with the programs you've written to send and receive data?

Answer (score 2):

Since the comments are getting rather lengthy, it might be better to turn them into an answer altogether.

If your app is not receiving data until a certain quantity is retrieved, then chances are, there is some sort of buffering going on behind the scenes.  A good example (not saying this applies to you directly) is that if you or the underlying libraries are using `InputStream.readLine()` or `InputStream.read(bytes)`, then it will block until it receives a newline or `bytes` number of bytes before returning.  Judging by the fact that your program seems to retrieve all of the data when a certain threshold is reached, it sounds like this is the case.

A good way to debug this is, use Wireshark.  Wireshark doesn't care about your program--its analyzing the raw packets that are sent to and from your computer, and can tell you whether or not the issue is on the sender or the receiver.

If you use Wireshark and see that the data from the first send is arriving on your physical machine well before the second, then the issue lies with your receiving end.  If you're seeing that the first packet arrives at the same time as the second packet, then the issue lies with the sender.  Without seeing the code, its hard to say what you're doing and what, specifically, is causing the data to only show up after receiving more than 2-3 bytes--but until then, this behavior describes exactly what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

There are several probable causes of this:

1. Cellular data networks are not "always-on".  Depending on the underlying technology, there can be a substantial delay between when a first packet is sent and when IP connectivity is actually established.  This will be most noticeable after IP networking has been idle for some time.
2. Your receiver may not be correctly checking the socket for readability.  Regardless of what high-level APIs you may be using, underneath there needs to be a call to `select()` to check whether the socket is readable.  When a datagram arrives, `select()` *should* unblock and signal that the socket descriptor is readable.  Alternatively, but less efficiently, you could set the socket to non-blocking and poll it with a read.  Polling wastes CPU time when there is no data and delays detection of arrival for up to the polling interval, but can be useful if for some reason you can't spare a thread to wait on `select()`.
3. I said above that `select()` should signal readability on a watched socket when data arrives, but this behavior can be modified by the socket's "Receive low-water mark".  The default value is usually 1, meaning any data will signal readability.  But if `SO_RCVLOWAT` is set higher (via `setsockopt()` or a higher-level equivalent), then readability will be not be signaled until more than the specified amount of data has arrived.  You can check the value with `getsockopt()` or whatever API is equivalent in your environment.

Item 1 would cause the first datagram to actually be delayed, but only when the IP network has been idle for a while and not once it comes up active.  Items 2 and 3 would only make it appear to your program that the first datagram was delayed: a packet sniffer at the receiver would show the first datagram arriving on time.